# p-values of scikit-learn LogisticRegressionCV?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, p-value

I'm using scikit-learn's [LogisticRegressionCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html).  Looks like the coefs_ field are the logistic regression coefficients.  Is there any way to get p-values,  z-values, or some measure of uncertainty for each feature?  (For example, as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129958/glm-in-r-which-pvalue-represents-the-goodness-of-fit-of-entire-model) in R.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, scikit-learn does not have any such methods for the logistic regression (nor for the linear regression as a matter of fact). I found this which might be of interest for you, but honestly, I would try to stick to R for such tasks if you can.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15398/how-to-get-p-value-and-confident-interval-in-logisticregression-with-sklearn